# Kubernetes send HTTP request from Pods

Tags: kubernetes

Currently I have an Kubernetes cluster which is to analyze Video Feeds and send particular results based on the video. I wish to send an HTTP request from my Kubernetes pod from from time to time if the requested Video needs to be retrieved over the internet. However all of these requests seem to Fail. When I issued a CURL command in the shell of the container I receive an error message saying

```
could not resolve host
```

I have looked into a few answers and many of them involve exposing a port in the container running a server to the Kubernetes node and making it publicly available through a external IP which I have already Implemented.

I am still very much a Novice in this area. So any guidance is appreciated

Comment: It is unclear what your environment looks like. Can you post your YAML manifests and output of "kubectl get pod" and "kubectl get svc"?

Comment: That generally means that DNS is not happy. How are you running kubernetes?

Comment: @coderanger. Yes thank you. I looked at the kube-dns pods status and noticed that they were pending. I increased the memory of the node and it continued to work.

Comment: This however leads me to the question. How exactly does one determine the memory required? Is there a recommended value or is it dependant more on the usecase. I am using GKE by the way.

Comment: It entirely depends on what you want to run.

Comment: You want to make HTTP request outside cluster or within the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in comments, kube-dns was unavailable due to resource constraints.